# php: 5 length string numbers in a 400 by 10

Tags: php

How can I generate strings of 5 numbers and store them in a 400 by 10 array in PHP?

I have done this but failed to put them in a 2-D array:

```
<?php
function randgen(){

    $result="";
    $chars="0123456789";
    $charArray=str_split($chars);
    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
        $randitem=array_rand($charArray);
        $result .=$charArray[$randitem];
    }
    echo $result;
}

for($y=1;$y<400;$y++){
   echo randgen().'<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: This sounds very much like homework to me

Answer (score 0):

first, your function randgen should return something instead of echo-ing. That way you can do something with the return value (store it in an array).
Then, to fill a 2-dimensional array you need 2 counters so you can access the array at coordinates [x][y] (or $i and $j as in my example).

```
function randgen(){
  $result="";
  $chars="0123456789";
  $charArray=str_split($chars);
  for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    $randitem=array_rand($charArray);
    $result .=$charArray[$randitem];
  }
  return $result;
}

$arr2d = array();

for($i = 0; $i < 400; $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j < 10; $j++){
        $arr2d[$i][$j] = randgen();
    }
}

print_r($arr2d);
```